# Polymorphic and has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have set up a polymorphic association in my app. A picture belongs to both a scoreboard model and a user model as pictureable. Each scoreboard and user has_one picture. I also have nested routes where pictures resource is nested inside a user and scoreboard resource.

Routes File for the users:

```
resources :users do
  resources :picture
end

resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
  member do
    post :reply
    post :restore
    post :mark_as_read
  end

  collection do
    delete :empty_trash
  end
end
```

Routes file for the scoreboard:

```
resources :scoreboards do 
  member do
    put :favourite
    get :deleteteams
    get :deleteschedules
  end

  resources :invitations, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :comments
  resources :teams, only: [:edit, :create, :destroy, :update]
  resources :schedules 
  resources :picture
end
```

I have setup a picture controller. The code is given below.

```
class PictureController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_pictureable

  def new 
    @picture = @pictureable.build_picture                              
  end                                               

  def create
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:picture)
  end

  def load_pictureable
    klass = [User, Scoreboard].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
    @pictureable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"]) 
  end
end
```

My new form is given below:

```
 <div id= "uploadphoto">
   <%= form_for([@pictureable, @picture], url: scoreboard_picture_path, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
     <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png', id: "files", class: "hidden" %>
     <label for="files" id="picture"><h4 id="picturetext">Click Here to Upload Picture</h4></label>
       <div class="modal" id="modal-1">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">Position and Crop your Image</div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="upload-preview">
                <img id="image" /></img>
               </div>
               <%= f.submit "upload photo" %>
             </div>
           <div class="modal-footer"> Click Anywhere Outside the box to Cancel</div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is with the URL. This gives me the following error.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"picture", :scoreboard_id=>"13"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I am not sure why it redirects me to the show action, I assume its probably the nested routes.I don't know what the problem is. I thought I had resolved it by passing the following URL `new_scoreboard_picture_path`. However, when I press upload photo, It would take me back to the same URL. This makes sense because I am explicitly stating the URL in the new form. However, that is incorrect. It would be a great help if someone could help me figure out what the issue is. I have only included the relevant code. However, if i am missing anything please do let me know. Any explanation as to why I am getting this error would also clarify my though process. This is the first time working with polymorphic associations. Any sort of help would be great!!

Comment: Please follow rails controller naming convention from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#controller-naming-convention). Could you paste the rendered form HTML code from the browser?

Comment: It will help if you could also show `routes.rb` code

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I have edited my original question and included all the relevant routes file for scoreboard and user.

Comment: maybe you're missing new in `scoreboard_picture_path` -> <%= form_for ... url: `new_scoreboard_picture_path` ... %>?

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario, I tried that previously. It works but when i submit the form I get an error. The URL doesn't work when I try to do a post request. For example, If i go to the URL users/1/picture/new. It works but when I submit the form, it strictly takes me back to the new_scoreboard_picture_path.

Comment: Oh you're right sorry. you should use `scoreboard_pictures_path` (note the `s`) as the url. Because by Rails CRUD convention, POST-ing to the resource path (/scoreboards/1/pictures) will be assigned to Pictures#create.. Just in case you don't know: GET-ing a resource path (/scoreboards/1/pictures) will be assigned to Pictures#index. However, what you should pass-in are `@scoreboard` and `@picture`. So `<%= form_for [@pictureable, @picture]` should be something like `<%= form_for [@scoreboard, @picture]`. You can sitll do this but you'll have to implement the logic on the controller yourself.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario picture model belongs to two other models users and scoreboards. I have a behavior in my controller which detects which resource it is and builds a picture with it. The method is called load_pictureable. So it meakes sense for me to pass pictureable and picture in the URL. scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[scoreboard_id]) would strictly attach it to scoreboard. Atleast, that's what i think

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario Also, just a side note, My controller is called picture not pictures. Do you think that might be causing the problem.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario, Ok I think that was the problem. So I changed the resource name picture to pictures. This is the naming convention for rails and therefore the routes. I changed the routes resources to pictures as well. I got rid of scoreboard_pictures_path url. This makes sense because pictures won't always be nested inside scoreboards. Everything seems to be working properly. I think everything is correct

Comment: oh i see. so @pictureable is already the polymorph associated object. So your form_for should not have a url: because it can either be `dashboard_pictures_path` or `user_pictures_path` depending on the model of @pictureable. So, I think you should only use `<%= form_for [@pictureable, @picture] %>` because Rails automatically creates the path from these two. It will be either `dashboard_pictures_path` or `user_pictures_path`. Yeah, by convention it should be plural because you're using `resource :picture` in which it a resource (with automatically assumes you have index,show,new,create...)

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario, Thank you for helping me debug the problem. I appreciate it. I knew it was something small. Anyhow, I highly appreciate the help. Thanks!!

Comment: It's good to hear that it worked. However, just a warning, you might want to test `[@pictureable, @picutre]` where `@pictureable` is a User and not a Scoreboard object. Because I have a feeling that it worked for you because `@pictureable` was a scoreboard in which you hardcoded the url: scoreboard_pictures_path, but it might not worked if `@pictureable` is a User. Try removing the url: altogether and just use `[@pictureable, @picture]` in form_for, because it should automatically determine the path. No  worries, glad I could help :)

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario, Thats exactly how i tested it. I removed the path completely. i just had [@pictureable, @picture] in the form. I tested both nested routes on a user and scoreboard. So ya, I think '@pictureable' is also a user and not just a scoreboard. I have the same new form but without the url

Answer (score 0):

I would use inheritance and two separate controllers instead:

```
# the base controller
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_pictureable

  def new 
    @picture = @pictureable.build_picture                              
  end                                               

  def create
    @picture = @pictureable.build_picture
    if @picture.save
      do_redirect
    else
      render_errors
    end
  end

  def destroy
    # ...
  end

  private

  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:picture)
  end

  # Finds the picturable based on the module name of the class
  # for examples `Pets::PicturesController` will look for
  # Pet.find(params[:pet_id])
  def find_pictureable
    # this looks at the class name and extracts the module name
    model_name = self.class.deconstantize.singularize
    @pictureable = model_name.constanize.find(params["#{model_name}_id"])
  end

  # subclasses can override this to whatever they want
  def do_redirect
    redirect_to @pictureable
  end

  # subclasses can override this to whatever they want
  def render_errors
    render :new
  end
end
```

Then setup the routes:

```
resources :users do
  resource :picture, controller: 'users/pictures'
end

resources :scoreboards do
  resource :picture, controller: 'scoreboards/pictures'
end
```

Since a user/scoreboard can have only one picture we are using `resource` and not `resources`. This sets up the routes for singular resource. Use `rake routes` to see the difference for yourself. For example you create a picture with `POST /users/:user_id/picture`.

We then setup the child controllers:

```
# app/controllers/users/pictures_controller.rb
class Users::PicturesController < PicturesController
end

 # app/controllers/scoreboards/pictures_controller.rb
class Scoreboards::PicturesController < PicturesController
end
```

This allows a high degree of customization without a jumble of `if/else` or `switch` statements. Also this safeguards against a malicious user passing `params[:user_id]` to manipulate a users picture. You should never use user input to determine classes or database tables.

Also you do not need to explicitly specify the form url:

```
<%= form_for([@pictureable, @picture], html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
```

Will use `users_picture_path(user_id: @pictureable.id)` or the same for scoreboards.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

Comment: I haven't added it for brevity but you should consider a cleanup step where you remove the orphaned Picture records.